# How to notate that a predicate holds for all elements in a set.

Tags: relations, quantifiers

I want to notate that a predicate holds for all elements in a set. Currently I have the following:
$\forall (a,c) \in R^{k+1}(\exists b \in A((a,b) \in R \land (b,c) \in R))$
I want to say that for all ordered pairs (a,c) in $R^{k+1}$ the following applies: There exists an element b in A such that: the order pairs (a,b) and (b,c) are an element of R. Is this notation right or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Thanks for the answers. I will change the parenthesis. This is indeed unclear. R denotes a relation, a set of ordered pairs. $R^{k+1}$ also denotes a relation. But it has different elements from R. Would switching from a, b and c to x, y and z make it easier to read? 
Thanks very much in advance

Comment: It seems you are using $(a, c)$ as an ordered pair, just we use $(x, y)$. They are each elements in $\mathbb R^2$ as are $(a, b), (b, c)\in \mathbb R^2.$  It is very unclear what you are trying to say.  Do you mean to denote a relation $R$, such that a \is related to b, and b is related to c?  Then you'll still need to try to make your post clearer.

Comment: Yes, I indeed am trying to say that a is related to b and b is related to C. And thanks for your answer. I edited my post.

Comment: Could you say more about $A$? To me it makes sense to see $A$ as a subset of reals.  It seems, given your comment and correction, that R denotes some relation such that for all $(a, c) \in R$ with $a, c \in A$,  there $\exists b \in A$ such that $(a, b) \in R$ and $(b, c) \in R$.

Comment: I'm confused by the exponent $k+1$ of the relation $R$. Are you trying to prove, by induction, that $$\forall(a, c)\in R^n(\exists b \in A((a, b)\in R \land (b, c) \in R.)$$ Please say more about set $A$.  Are $a, c\in A$?

Comment: $R^{k+1}$ denotes all paths of length k+1 in R. I am trying to prove that if R is transitive then all $R^n$ for n is integer and bigger than zero are also contained in R. R is a relation on A. So R contains ordered pairs in which both elements belong to A. A is just a set. It could be anything. But we need to have some kind of domain for R. But by transitivity the next step would be to conclude that $\forall (a, c) \in R^{k+1}((a, c) \in R) $. If R is transitive this holds.

Comment: @LaurensOp'tZandt OK, I figured you were trying to do something like that. OK, then please look at my suggested sentence where you recursively generate $R^{k+1}$ out of $R^k$ and $R$ itself. That is: all paths of length $k+1$ are the paths of length $k$ to which we add one more step.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late, Laurens!  Now things are making more sense. Have you received the help you need through the comment and answer of @Bram28 ?  If it helped, think about upvoting the answer. (Click on $\uparrow$ above the votes score on the left of the post). If it really helped, you can even accept the answer by clicking on the grey $\checkmark$ on the left side of the answer, that once you click on it, turns green.

Comment: @amWhy And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symbolization is fine ... though as amWhy comments, usually in logic we use for variables things like $x$, $y$, and $z$, as $a$, $b$, and $c$ are usually used to denote specific objects. So:

$\forall (x,z) \in R^{k+1} \: \Big( \exists y \in A \: \Big( (x,y) \in R \land (y,z) \in R \Big) \Big)$

**EDIT**

OK, now that I understand that you want $R^k$ to mean all paths of length $k$, you should recursively define $R^{k+1}$ as:

$\forall (x,z) \in R^{k+1} \: \Big( \exists y \in A \: \Big( (x,y) \in R^k \land (y,z) \in R \Big) \Big)$

In fact, this sentence says that *only* the paths that can be created as such are in $R^{k+1}$ ... not  *all* and only such paths (e.g the statement would be true if $R^{k+1} =\{\}$. So, what you really want is something like:

$\forall x,z \in A \Big( (x,z) \in R^{k+1} \leftrightarrow \exists y \in A \Big( (x,y)\in R^k \land (y,z) \in R \Big) \Big)$

That is, there is a path of length $k+1$ from $x$ to $z$ if and only if there is a path of length $k$ from $x$ to $y$, and one more step from $y$ to $z$.

If you want to prove that if $R$ is transitive then for any $k$ all pairs in $R^{k}$ are in $R$, you want to prove that for all $k$:

$\forall (x,y) \in R^k : (x,y) \in R$

If you want to prove this using formal logic (i.e. Using a formal logic derivation), however, you will need to explicitly quantify over the $k$ as well though, so in both your definition as well as your goal you will have to add $\forall k$ at the beginning (or, if $k$ cannot be used as a variable, use a proper variable). And then you will also need some formalization of induction, where that formalization can deal with the $k$ in $R^k$ ... So maybe even define a function $f(R,k)$ instead of $R^k$ ... How technical/formal do you need to get?

Comment: Thank you very much: I currently generated it like this: $R^{k+1} = \{ (a,c) \in A \times A \vert \exists b \in A((a,b) \in R^k \land (b,c) \in R) \}$. I will change to x y and z. Then I used the IH to denote that $(a,b) \in R^k$ will also be in R. Then I used the definition of transitivity: $(a,b)\in R \land (b,c) \in R \implies (a,c) in R$. This led to the same conclusion as you suggested. I needed to prove it using mathematical induction. You have been very helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: I understand...